# Как DLP-системы перехватывают защищенные сообщения

Tags: https, шифрование, взлом

В описании многих DLP-систем (Data Leak Prevention) указываются такие возможности, как чтение https, контроль за мессенжерами, в том числе Whatsapp, Telegram. Как такое возможно? Разве point-to-point шифрование не делает это невозможным?

Comment: Если система ставится на анализируемый комп, то она получает полный контроль над ним и может делать что угодно. Для https — подсунуть фейковый сертификат в доверенные; для мессенджеров — внедриться в процесс и вытащить незашифрованный текст прямо из оперативной памяти, или можно вытащить ключ шифрования из той же самой памяти, почему бы и нет

Comment: @andreymal вы можете добавить это как ответ. Только объясните в двух словах, как можно подсунуть фейковый сертификат и получить доступ к оперативке какого-либо процесса